# Show a Modal Window while a db query is taking place

Tags: javascript, forms, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a form as below:

```
<FORM id='CSVUpdateForm' action='update.asp' type='GET' target="responseFrame">
<input type='text' Name='PCNM' />
<INPUT TYPE='submit' name='ENTRY' >
</FORM>
```

Now in `update.asp` I have a VBScript function that will insert a long list of queries into the Oracle database.
I want to display some sort of message (modal window) while the user waits for the query to finish. The user should not be able to do any operations while the query processes.

How can I do this?

I tried by opening a modal window using `showModalDialog("")` but while doing so it will halt any operations as long as it opened.

How can I keep showing some sort of information while the query is being processed? and after the query is completed I would like to close the window.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with Oracle or mysql

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Hi. I removed it although my intention was to include it because I thought there might be some relation to Oracle db.

Comment: This looks like Classic ASP not ASP.Net, which is it?

Comment: @lankymart Yes it's Classic ASP not ASP.net. My bad. I'll correct it.

Comment: The approach I would take is use a [light-box javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) library to display a custom message and perform the post via AJAX, that way you can detect when the script completes and close the light-box. [Here is a lightweight one](http://sorgalla.com/lity/) that supports native Javascript and displaying custom dialogs.

Comment: Just to add to @Lankymart's suggestion that if your ASP site uses session then you will want to ensure that the content of your modal window is not produced via another call to the ASP server as otherwise this call will queue behind the page running the queries. If you did want to do that, maybe to indicate progress somehow, then make the content of the modal run with ASP session disabled by setting the value of EnableSessionState as the top of the modal ASP page.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat if I was going to do that I'd just make sure the message was populated first before calling the long running script via AJAX.

Comment: @Lankymart Sure that would be good too. But say for example that the OP has 20 queries to execute. If he can update another table with a progress counter 1 - 20 as each completes then he could read this via ajax and drive a progress bar in the modal window to make for a better UX.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not using AJAX currently, so what I did was I opened a new window before the form was submitted using Javascript and then after the completion of the query I sent Javascript Close Window command as a response.

Comment: @Raxak No worries then - looks like you have it covered. Other thing to think about is increasing the timeouts for the ASP script and DB connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

showModalDialogue() is IE only. As has been suggested you need a javascript modal window.  There are many modal libraries around but if you want to do something simple then here is a DIY modal requiring only jquery.  This snippet will run right here in SO.

```js
function doModal(opts) {

  $("body").data("cssoverflow", $("body").css("overflow"))
  $("body").css({
    overflow: "hidden"
  })

  $("#ovl").css({
    display: ""
  })
  $("#theTitle").html(opts.title)
  $("#theMsg").html(opts.message)

  $("#" + opts.eleId)
    .css({
      width: opts.w,
      height: opts.h,
      display: ""
    })
    .css({
      left: ($(window).width() - opts.w) / 2,
      top: ($(window).height() - opts.h) / 2
    })
}


$("#theButton").on("click", function(e) {

  alert("You clicked the button")

})

$("#theCloseButton").on("click", function(e) {
  $("body").css({
    overflow: $("body").data("cssoverflow")
  })
  $("#theModal").hide()
  $("#ovl").hide()
})

$("#theShowButton").on("click", function(e) {
  // Call doModal with options as below to open the modal
  doModal({
    eleId: "theModal",
    w: 500,
    h: 250,
    title: "Something happens",
    message: "Somewhere a server is busy doing something..."
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ovl" style="position: absolute;display:none;top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.6; background-color: black;"></div>
<div id="theModal" style="position: absolute;display:none;border: 1px solid silver; background-color: white; padding: 25px; z-index: 10;">
  <h1 id="theTitle">
  Message title
  </h1>
  <p id="theMsg">
    Your message goes here....
  </p>
  <button id="theCloseButton">
    Close
  </button>
  <p>

  </p>
</div>

<p style="height: 500px;">

  <button id="theButton">
    Click me
  </button>
  <button id="theShowButton">
    Show modal
  </button>
</p>
```